# Error calling template method in "templated-base-class"

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, generic-programming

The following code does not compile, why is that? And how can I fix this?

```
struct A{
    template<int N> int get() { return N; }
};

template <typename X>
struct B : public X {
    template<int N> int get() {
        return X::get<N>();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    B<A> b;
    return b.get<5>();
}
```

Compiler error:

```
test.cxx: In member function ‘int B<X>::get()’:
test.cxx:8:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
test.cxx: In member function ‘int B<X>::get() [with int N = 5, X = A]’:
test.cxx:15:25:   instantiated from here
test.cxx:8:30: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to  binary ‘operator<’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must disambiguate it, like so:

```
template<int N>int get() {
    return X::template get<N>();
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need of disambiguation? OP is strictly calling `X::get<N>();`

Comment: @sad_man: Without instantiating X during the first pass, we don't know that `get` is a member template. `X::get<N>()` is interpreted as `X::get less_than N greater_than ()` which is an error.

Comment: @sad_man: Basically C++ rules don't allow a situation where the same code could mean both a call to a member function template and a series of comparisons, depending on the specialization of X. (VC++ gets it wrong, AFAIK.)