# Accessing templated methods of a templated base class

Tags: c++, qt, templates, gcc4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error calling template method in “templated-base-class”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755003/error-calling-template-method-in-templated-base-class)

The following code compiles with MSVC10 but not with gcc 4.2.1:

```
template<class BaseQNativeWindow>
class NativeWindow : public BaseQNativeWindow
{
public:
  NativeWindow(AIPanelPlatformWindow handle) : BaseQNativeWindow(handle)
  {}

protected:
  virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
  {
    QList<QWidget *> childrenList;
    childrenList = BaseQNativeWindow::findChildren< QWidget * >(); // GCC ERROR
    foreach(QWidget *child, childrenList)
    {
      child->close();
    }
  }
};
```

This is what gcc complains about:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token  
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token  
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

`findChildren` is a templated method that `BaseQNativeWindow` must provide. It seems that gcc assumes that `findChildren` is not a template even before knowing what type `BaseQNativeWiindow` is. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should work... Try if `BaseQNativeWindow::template findChildren< QWidget* >()` solves it

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132) might help.

Comment: Indeed adding "template" solves it, thank you. Need to brush up my template knowledge. I'll accept your answer if you create it :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to say:

```
BaseQNativeWindow::template findChildren< QWidget * >()
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Since `findChildren` is a dependent name, its meaning must be disambiguated.